# Chart.js won't draw the line on chart line

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I'm using Chart.js v3.7.0 on React as follows

```js
export default function MyChart(props) {
const {
    chartData = [10, 1, 5, 4, 20, 25, 10]
  } = props

  const canvasRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    const chartConfig = {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        datasets: [{
          labels: chartData.map(() => null),
          data: chartData,
          borderColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0)',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0)',
          label: 'Open',
          borderWidth: 1,
          fill: true
        }]
      },
      options: {
        plugins: {
          responsive: true
        }
      }
    }
    new Chart(canvasRef.current, chartConfig)
  }, [])

  return (<>
    <canvas ref={canvasRef} />
  </>)
}
```

It draws the gridlines, and the legend shows with correct coloring. The vertical axis even scales accordingly if you mess around with `chartData`. But the curve won't show up. What's wrong with this? Is this something React-related or am I using the `datasets` wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The labels array needs to be at the same level as your datasets like so:

```js
data:{
  labels: [],
  datasets: []
}
```